# Check if the month changes and reset the cells if the month has changed

Tags: vba, excel

I am having the current date (TODAY()) in A4 cell. The format is Nov-15 and Values from B4:T4. I want to reset the values to 0 when the month changes from Nov to Dec. The following is my try,

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Sheets("Output").Range("A4").Value Like "01*" Then Range("B4:T4").ClearContents
End Sub
```

But my problem is, The sheet wont be opened every day. Suppose if the excel sheet is not opened on 1st, the values wont get reset. Can we modify this macro to run whenever the excel sheets open and check for the month on the previous run and if it has changed, we can reset the contents of the cell.

Can anybody help me in doing this?

Comment: `to run whenever the excel sheets open` but you do have it set to run when it opens via `Workbook_Open()`?

Comment: @findwindow Yeah I already set to run when the excel opens. But if the excel doesn't open on 1st, the contents wont get reset right? I want to check the month on the previous run of the excel and if it has changed, I want to reset it. that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: You're going to need to store the value of "today" on workbook_close *somewhere* and compare it on workbook_open

Comment: @Raystafarian I tried that. But since it is today value, it also changes in the next run. I was not able to paste the values of today in one cell. That is where I need some help.

Comment: I am confused. If it's not getting opened, why does it need to update?

Comment: That's why you need to store the value somewhere not at the function.

Comment: @Raystafarian I didn't mean to steal your answer. I was working it up and posted it just to see that you and I were going in the same direction.

Comment: @ScottCraner no worries!

Comment: Same to both of you - ScottCraner & Raystafarian... Once I caught on more clearly after the OP's comment on my original answer, I edited my answer to fix the dilemma.

Comment: @Raystafarian Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Raystafarian stated you will need to store the present month in a cell.  I have it in Z4, you can change it.

Try this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    if Sheets("Output").Range("Z4").value > 0 then
        If Month(Sheets("Output").Range("A4")) <> Sheets("Output").Range("Z4") Then
            Range("B4:T4").ClearContents
            Sheets("Output").Range("Z4") = Month(Sheets("Output").Range("A4"))
        End If
    End IF
End Sub
```

Comment: nice. cleaner than my solution :) The only caveat is that it will clear the cells the *very first* it's used unless the current month value is stored in `Z4` before the next workbook open.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @SilentObserver Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

Store the date each time the workbook closes and compare against the date on opening.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
      If Month(.Range("A4")) <> Month (.Cells(.Rows.Count,.Columns.Count))Then .Range("B4:T4").ClearContents
End With

End Sub
```

Put this in the workbook close event.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Close()

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
     .Cells(.Rows.Count,.Columns.Count).Value = .Range("A4")
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Scott Holtzmann Thanks for the reply. But if the sheet is not opened on 1st date, it doesn't reset right? that is my problem.